# HTML5: enum instead of ul for inline lists inside paragraphs?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Considering the following paragraph:

```
So in the first set, we start to mix those 3 codes:

- AA
- BB
- CC

with those codes:

- Aa
- Ab
- Ac


to get the perfect result we're looking for.
```

Is this paragraph semantically incorrect?
If not, what's the html5 way of writing it?

1. If I use ul, then it splits the paragraph in three parts, which is semantically inexact (isn't it?).
2. I can use br or span, but then I have to do all the formatting myself.

Are those the two only ways we have?
If so, why not having an enum element, like this:

```
<p>
So in the first set, we start to mix those 3 codes:

<enum>
<ei>AA</ei>
<ei>BB</ei>
<ei>CC</ei>
</enum>

with those codes:

<enum>
<ei>Aa</ei>
<ei>Ab</ei>
<ei>Ac</ei>
</enum>

to get the perfect result we're looking for.
</p>
```

Would that make any sense?

I would like to propose that to the W3C, do you think that's a good idea?

If not, why?

Answer (score 1):

I think using description list is the best way for the above particular example like;

```
<dl>
  <dt>So in the first set, we start to mix those 3 codes:</dt>
  <dd>AA</dd>
  <dd>BB</dd>
  <dd>CC</dd>
  <dt>with those codes:</dt>
  <dd>Aa</dd>
  <dd>Ab</dd>
  <dd>Ac</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but dl is also a block level element. I'm looking for an inline level list element, but apparently it doesn't exist.

Comment: You've welcome! You're right description list (dl) is a block element but unordered list (ul) is also a block element and you mention it in your question that you can use it. So, I answer for it.If you mean that using unordered list independently (not in paragraph), I suggest to use decription list instead of unordered list. BTW if you look in my answer I am not use the dl in the paragraph and it is not divide the paragraph in the three part like you say.

Comment: Besides, inline mean not new line. That is logically incorrect because lists elements must start with a new line not inline :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer that satisfies me: https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/4685. 
Basically, breaking the "p" element is not a big deal, as the p element is an html paragraph, which is different from an english paragraph.

So, the html way of doing a list inside a paragraph, is simply to break the p before the list, and create another one after, like this (for instance):

```
<p>The list should be</p>
<ul>
  <li>responsive</li>
  <li>short</li>
  <li>precise</li>
  <li>easy to use</li>
</ul>
<p>to do all the things I want</p>
```